# What's the white tall tower with a tank near Space Shuttle launch pad?

Tags: space-shuttle, launch-site

Here's neat [image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle#mediaviewer/File:Space_shuttles_Atlantis_%28STS-125%29_and_Endeavour_%28STS-400%29_on_launch_pads.jpg):

[image: two Space Shuttles and two towers]

On the right there's a tall white tower with a rounded tank on top looking much like a water tower. There's another one right behind the first one opposing the other spaceship.

What's that tower and what is it for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the jets of water often under rocket engines during launch?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-jets-of-water-often-under-rocket-engines-during-launc)

Comment: Here's an illustration of the use of water (from water towers) during the launch of a Saturn V (from 4:00 minutes into it): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPW7ZqtW5U4

Comment: It's clearly a *War of the Worlds* alien in disguise...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This tower is 290 ft. high. It has storage capacity of 300000 gallons of water used during STS launches to protect the Orbiter and its payload from acoustic vibrations due to SRB's firing. The pipes beneath the tower are the main distribution area.

For more information, including a virtual walkaround, please visit http://nasatech.net/ntSubPad39A_PAGE.html, in particular [this view](http://nasatech.net/ntSubPad39A/Pad39AH2OSSSOverDistrib130412/).

Comment: Come on, tell us it's a *War of the Worlds* alien in disguise...

Comment: @smci - I can neither confirm nor deny it.

Comment: [Here is extended high speed camera footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFwqZ4qAUkE) of space shuttle launches showing all the water cooling going on. In it, they specifically point out these towers and their purpose (as stated in the answer).