# What's inside the white round elevated container next to the Falcon 9 starting base?

Tags: rockets, falcon-9, falcon-heavy

On images of the Falcon 9 start you see a kind of round elevated container (on the left hand side of the picture).

What does it contain and why is it elevated?

[image: Start of Falcon 9 - From NASA - https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasakennedy/26250304828/in/photostream/, Gemeinfrei, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=66191455]

Comment: Water, elevated to give pressure to the lines without needing pumps.

Comment: Duplicate: "What's the white tall tower with a tank near Space Shuttle launch pad?" - https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8187/40489; find answer there - 290 ft. high.tower, storage capacity of 300000 gallons of water used during launches.

Comment: Yes, duplicate of [What's the white tall tower with a tank near Space Shuttle launch pad?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/whats-the-white-tall-tower-with-a-tank-near-space-shuttle-launch-pad)

Comment: Huh, they painted "SpaceX" on it. Cheeky.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate, I hadn't found it before!